# How to use the value of a Python variable as the callback name?

Tags: python, callback, variable-assignment

Edit: The following is a simplified code of a more complex example.

```
def lottery(amount, callback=None):
    print(f'You spent {amount} on a lottery ticket.')
    if callback:
        callback(amount)

def win(amount):
    print(f'You won ${amount * 1000}!!!')

def lose(amount):
    print(f"Sorry, you spent {amount} and didn't win anything.")
```

Edit: The 'lottery' function is from a third-party package. I would prefer not to modify their code.

The following works, but they aren't what I am looking for.

```
lottery(100, win)
```

Output:

You spent 100 on a lottery ticket.
You won $100000!!!

```
lottery(100, callback=win)
```

Output:

You spent 100 on a lottery ticket.
You won $100000!!!

```
lottery(100, lose)
```

Output:

You spent 100 on a lottery ticket.
Sorry, you spent 100 and didn't win anything.

```
lottery(100, callback=lose)
```

You spent 100 on a lottery ticket.
Sorry, you spent 100 and didn't win anything.

**What I'm looking for is to continue to use a callback and have a variable hold a value of either 'win', 'lose', [Edit: or additional functions like 'win_1', 'win_2', ..., 'win_n' or 'lose_1', 'lose_2', ..., 'lose_n'] and use that variable in the same place as the callback name.**

Wishful example:

```
win_lose = 'win'
lottery(100, win_lose)
```

Edit: the string 'win' is built on the fly like:

```
'win' + '_' + str(index)
```

or

```
'lose' + '_' + str(index)
```

Wishful output:

You spent 100 on a lottery ticket.
You won $100000!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
def lottery(amount, win_lose):
    print(f'You spent {amount} on a lottery ticket.')
    if win_lose =="win":
        print(f'You won ${amount * 1000}!!!')
    if win_lose =="lose":
        print(f"Sorry, you spent {amount} and didn't win anything.")
    
#Example
win_lose = 'win'
lottery(100, win_lose)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. Unfortunately,  it's not using a callback function using a variable per my original challenge to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You know you can assign the function objects to variables, right? You could just do `win_lose = win` (no quotes) and the code would work. If you want a string with the name of the function, you can use its `__name__` attribute: `print(callback.__name__)` will print " win" if that function is the passed in callback.

Otherwise, if both functions are on the same module, you  can retrieve the functin object from its name by using the dictionary returned by `globals()` - that would do exactly what you are asking - I am just not sure if that is really what you'd need:

```
def lottery(amount, callback_name=None):
    callback = globals().get(callback_name)
    print(f'You spent {amount} on a lottery ticket.')
    if callback:
        callback(amount)

def win(amount):
    print(f'You won ${amount * 1000}!!!')

def lose(amount):
    print(f"Sorry, you spent {amount} and didn't win anything.")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing both solutions. They do work but not for my particular situation. I simplified a more complex problem but I did a poor job of explaining it. The "lottery" function is in a third-party package so I would prefer a solution without touching their code. The callback variable I want to use could hold various values representing different functions determined on the fly. For example, it could hold function names like win_1, win_2, ... win_n or lose_1, lose_2, ... lose_n.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for my situation was creating an empty 'win_lose()' function and assigning the 'global()[]' dictionary outside of the functions to 'win_lose' as shown below.

```
def lottery(amount, callback=None):
    print(f'You spent {amount} on a lottery ticket.')
    if callback:
        callback(amount)

def win_lose(amount): pass

def win(amount):
    print(f'You won ${amount * 1000}!!!')

def lose(amount):
    print(f"Sorry, you spent {amount} and didn't win anything.")
```

Checking memory address for each function:

```
print(f'id(win_lose): {id(win_lose)}, id(win): {id(win)}, id(lose): {id(lose)}')
```

id(win_lose): 1668264920544, id(win): 1668264920832, id(lose): 1668264921696

```
win_lose = globals()['lose']
print(f'id(win_lose): {id(win_lose)}')
```

id(win_lose): 1668264921696

```
lottery(100, win_lose)
```

You spent 100 on a lottery ticket.
Sorry, you spent 100 and didn't win anything.

```
win_lose = globals()['win']
print(f'id(win_lose): {id(win_lose)}')
```

id(win_lose): 1668264920832

```
lottery(100, win_lose)
```

You spent 100 on a lottery ticket.
You won $100000!!!

What pitfalls are there with this approach?